# Replacing special characters like dots in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, search, replace

I have a search query from the user and I want to process it before applying to browser. since I'm using SEO with htaccess and the search url looks like this : /search/[user query] I should do something to prevent user from doing naughty things.. :) Like searching ../include/conf.php which will result in giving away my configuration file. I want to process the query like removing spaces, removing dots(which will cause problems), commas,etc.

```
var q = document.getElementById('q').value;
var q = q.replace(/ /gi,"+");
var q = q.replace(/../gi,"");
document.location='search/'+q;
```

the first replace works just fine but the second one messes with my query.. any solution to replacing this risky characters safely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I disable JavaScript or use `curl` I still can do "*naughty things*"? On the client side do the sanity escaping with:

```
encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('q').value)
```

and leave security checks to the server. You would be amazed what malicious user can do (using some escape sequences instead of plain `.` is the simplest example).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this server-side - it's too easy for someone to alter your JS in the page or switch it off altogether.  Your search script that runs server-side can't (as) easily be tampered with and can then filter the search consistently.

You might also want to restrict what the search returns... if it's able to show sensitive config files, your search may have a little too much reach.

Answer (score 0):

Dots in regular expressions match anything.  You need to escape them with a back-slash ('\'):

```
var q = q.replace(/\.\./gi,"");
```